# readdirSync cannot read encrypted home folder when accessing it directly

Tags: node.js

```
const fs = require("fs")

//const HOW = "/home/test/everything"

// const HOW = "/home/test/"
// This one fails. My home is encrypted and it cannot read directories, it gets the .Private file. I want to read files and directories in my home folder. But can't.

const HOW = "/home/test/folder/"
// This one works for some reason. It lists all the directories in the folder.

// const HOW = "folder"
// This one works as well 


var list = walk(HOW)

console.log(list)

// How do I get contents of /home/test (which happens to be my home folder).
// I'm both root and "test" user of the computer.
```

I'd like to have `walk()` work on `/home/test/`.

The code that fails:

```
var walk = function(dir) {
    var results = []
    var list = fs.readdirSync(dir)
    list.forEach(function(file) {
        file = dir + '/' + file
        var stat = fs.statSync(file)
        if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) results = results.concat(walk(file))
        else results.push(file)
    })
    return results
}
```

The exact line causing it (stack trace): `var stat = fs.statSync(file)`

The error is:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/test/.Private/###############################################################'
```

Where # is an amount of letters whose importance to safety is unknown to me.

Node.js doesn't have a problem addressing any folder contained within my home folder, but cannot address the home folder itself. Neither my own account nor root account can get access to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are adding an unnecessary `/`. Try changing

```
const HOW = "/home/test/folder/"
```

to

```
const HOW = "/home/test/folder"
```